# What's a free and open source alternative to TeamViewer (remote control software) for GNU/Linux?

Tags: open-source, remote-access, remote-desktop

So I'm running Debian 9.0 and I'm looking for a FOSS remote control software that allows me to remotely control other GNU/Linux' as well as Windows machines. Does such a thing exist?
It should be as userfriendly as to allow even tech-unsavvy users seeking help to set it up and if possible only require some password and id to be transmitted between the respective users.

And if not: why not? Isn't it "just" some encrypted connection between two machines over the Internet with standardized commands and protocols to remotely control mouse & keyboard and transfer the machine's graphics surface?

**Edit**: still looking for more answers, the solutions so far are not appropriate for casual users and require people to be tech-savvy, configure stuff or even use the command line.
To make it clearer: I'm just looking for a simple GUI that's easy / self-explanatory to use *just like TeamViewer is* no matter what underlying tech it uses - I don't really care about the protocols it uses as long as they are working & secure and the program userfriendly.

Comment: if you want a direct connection (which TeamViewer etc. does not!) and tech-unsavy users to be the server, i guess *reverse VNC* (also called *VNCI* or *VNC incoming*) is the solution.

Comment: Not really needed for Linux - any and all remote administration can be done via SSH, or if you *must* have a GUI, then X over SSH.

Comment: @ivanivan yes, but the tech-unsavy user in front of the server has to setup port-forwarding, or is there something like *"reverse SSH"* i don't know?

Comment: @DJCrashdummy - never seen a *nix box that didn't have ssh installed and running...

Comment: @ivanivan for sure, but that wasn't the point of my comment! -- the question is more... how to explain the 90-years-old grandma to setup port-forwarding, that you can use SSH on her pc? ...or even better to avoid this!

Comment: Is open-source free-software a must? You don't mention it in the body of your question. I don't know if you know already, but TeamViewer exists for Linux (as well as Android), too: https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/ You can access Windows machines from Linux and vice versa.

Comment: Gotomypc.com, free I think to a certain # of machines.

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm: you won't get sightly other answers to this question as long as you are asking for a local software, since you always will have to setup port-forwarding at one side to reach the computer. - this is because of the fundamentals how networks/routers/firewalls work... and yes this behavior is on purpose, without it running a device with network-access would be a security-nightmare!

Comment: it seems you are rather looking for a service which establishes a handshake between the two computers... and there are tons out there (browser-based, local software, with account, without account, etc...), but they rarely use "standardized commands/protocols" (or at least prohibit cooperation/federation), are hardly open source and therefor questionable how "secure" they are. :-/

Answer (score 7):

### the basics

1. the protocol you are looking for, would be [**VNC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) for a platform-independent solution.

   - *for *nix-environments [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System)over[SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) or [X2Go](https://wiki.x2go.org) may be a better choice and for a CLI only, SSH is the way to go.*
   - *maybe for windows [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) is also a better choice.*
2. but VNC has a big advantage for your use-case:
   it features a **"reverse connection"** to work around a [port-forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) for the server (the machine which should be controlled).

---

### the software

basically [**Gitso**](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gitso/) is a nice idea to simplify the process, have one GUI for both sides and the help seeking person needs just to enter the ip/address of the supporter.

[image: gitso-screenshots]

as you can see it is also multi-platform available, BUT it is inactive for years now (although there are some forks at github, to mention the most interesting: https://github.com/rastersoft/Gitso).
additional there are some issues i experienced, like incorrect display under linux (at least with some other client), connection-errors under windows10 and other shortcomings like unencrypted transfer, etc.

so i decided to use up-to-date and supported software with which i also can control things much better and use all the settings i want to:

1. as **viewer** (for linux as asked) i use and would suggest [**Remmina**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remmina):

   - it features a bunch of protocols (beside VNCi) via plugins
   - has nice features for managing connections and much more...
2. as **linux-server** i use [**x11vnc**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11vnc):
   it's like the Swiss Army knife of VNC-servers... to just name a few features:

   - it has a GUI and a even more powerful CLI
   - it uses the current display but also can create a new one
   - connections can be encrypted via SSL or also tunneling via SSH is possible
   - it supports authentication for example also via unix-passwords
   - and much more... i highly recommend to read the man-page!
3. as **windows-server** i guess [**UltraVNC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraVNC):

   - it looks like it's features can compete with x11vnc...
   - and the most important with it's SingleClick-feature you can create an easy to use reverseVNC-version.
   - there is even a walkthrough for creating your own branded UltraVNC SingleClick: https://www.uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-sc.html
4. as **mac-server** i have no clue what to use...
   <sub>*if anyone knows a good one with support for reverse VNC, please leave a comment or add it. thanks!*</sub>

---

### the usage

1. i would suggest to use a DDNS-service for your IP, so the tech-unsavvy user doesn't have to change anything. - if not, he has to enter your current ip-adress (which you have to tell him every time), and this can be from server to server more or less complicated...
2. since we are turning the server-/client-system a bit upside down with reverse VNC, you have to setup a **port-forwarding to** your machine with the **client**.
3. you have to **start** your **"client" first** to get it into a kind of listening mode...
4. and then **finally** the help seeking person **start**s his **reverse VNC server**... and your client will switch from it's listening mode to the usual remote view/control.

   the settings and the start of the server can or even must - since we are talking about different programs - be done in several ways...

   - *x11vnc:* i don't like the GUI (and guess for really tech-unsavvy users it won't be a pleasure to use) so i switched to the CLI... and now you can do everything you want!
     either simply copy&paste the one-liner, paste it into a little script which the help seeking person just has to start or for the perfectionists "hide" the script and create a launcher which transfers the look and handling into an usual program. --> either way, voila: one click/enter for the user.
   - *UltraVNC:* somehow you can create your own SingleClick.exe with all settings preset, that the help seeking person just has to start (even no installing required). --> sorry that i can't go into details for UltraVNC but i haven't used it for ages... my noobs and i are happy with linux, so no more need for windows-specials. ;-)